# JavaScript parallel thread for DOM related processing

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I have a resource consuming DOM (browser) related JavaScript process. When started it blocks the page (other DOM related processed). Is it possible to run this process in parallel asynchronously, and when it finished pass the result to main page? Web workers is not the case, as process works with DOM.

Can this be implemented with iframes? Does JS started in iframe block hosted page DOM too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it would be a prime example for using *WebWorkers*, but as you correctly mentioned you won't have a reference to a DOM there. Your only option is to decouple that process into smaller task's. If you can do that, you need to ask yourself two questions

- do the smaller tasks need to run sequentially ?
- can these tasks run asynchronously ?

If you can answer both questions with *No*, you can setup a *run-away script timer* and execute those tasks asynchronously. Example:

```
var taskList = [
    function() {},
    function() {},
    function() {},
    function() {}
    // a whole lot more entrys
];  // in a real-world scenario you would `.push()` values or functions

(function _loop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var start = Date.now();
        do {
            taskList.shift()();
        } while( taskList.length && Date.now() - start < 100)

        if( taskList.length ) setTimeout( _loop, 100 );
    },100);
}());
```

The above algorythm would execute the functions contained by `taskList` as fast as possible, but within a time-frame of 100ms max. This will ensure that the browser respectively the *UI thread* won't get blocked for longer than *100ms* during the processing. Hence the browser will stay *responsive*.

Comment: Thank you very much ) I will try to implement your approach, I believe I can break the process down into smaller pieces. Will mark as answer in case of success.

Comment: Heres a link to some code I wrote to help out with writing timer based  tasks with DOM access - https://github.com/jameswestgate/taskjs